# AddClass to <a> using jquery

Tags: jquery, addclass

I am trying to add a Class to the first link.

The code looks like this:

```
<p class="breadcrumb"> <a href="index.php"> Home </a> <a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
```

I don't know how to add a class to the first link "Home" (index.php) so i could style it with css.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(".breadcrumb a:first").addClass("itemhover");
</script>
```

This did not work.

Answer (score 4):

The element probably hasn't loaded. Delay your Javascript until all elements have been loaded with [`$(document).ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready):

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".breadcrumb a:first").addClass("itemhover");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the code in document ready.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(function(){
    $(".breadcrumb a:first").addClass("itemhover");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".breadcrumb a:first").addClass("itemhover");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding an id to the link

```
<p class="breadcrumb"> <a id="home" href="index.php"> Home </a> <a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
```

and then try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#home").addClass("itemhover");
});
```

Comment: in that case that will not work. thats why i was searching for a workaround ;)

Comment: in which case? adding the id? or in onReady event?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax are correct but there is some problem with CSS overriding you can use !important to you class attribute

example :

```
<script>
    $(function(){

        $(".breadcrumb a:first").addClass("itemhover");

    });
</script>



.itemhover{
        color : red !important;
}
```

Comment: i think you are not including js files for jQuery.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jscript/jquery.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Sample page :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN" --"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd"-->
<html>
<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryui.com/js/jquery.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.min.js"></script>

  <script>

    $(function(){
        $(".breadcrumb a:first").addClass("itemhover");
    });
  </script>

<style type="text/css">
.itemhover{
    color : red !important;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p class="breadcrumb"> <a href="index.php"> Home </a> 
<br />
<a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
</P>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "index.php:17Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )"